# Como passar valores de ViewBag para uma function Javascript em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, visual-studio

Tenho a seguinte ActionResult Controller em minha aplicação.
Nesta ActionResult tenho duas ViewBag que captura de uma desserialização valores de Longitude e Latitude originados de uma API da Google.

**Os valores chegam perfeitamente na ViewBag abaixo vindo assim -21.1234567 e -51.1234567**

```
    ViewBag.Latitude = Double.Parse(a1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    ViewBag.Longitude = Double.Parse(a2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Código abaixo da ActionResult**

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Empresa empresa = db.Empresa.Find(id);

    if (empresa == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[Numero]+[Endereco],+[Bairro],+[Estado]&key=MINHA CHAVE";

    url = url.Replace("[Numero]", empresa.Numero);
    url = url.Replace("[Endereco]", empresa.Endereco.Replace(" ", "+"));
    url = url.Replace("[Bairro]", empresa.Bairro.Replace(" ", "+"));
    url = url.Replace("[Estado]", empresa.Estado);

    string value = client.DownloadString(url);

    dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value);

    string a1 = dyn["results"][0].geometry.location.lat;

    string a2 = dyn["results"][0].geometry.location.lng;

    /* QUERO PASSAR OS VALORES ABAIXO PARA A VIEW */
    ViewBag.Latitude = Double.Parse(a1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    ViewBag.Longitude = Double.Parse(a2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return View(empresa);
}
```

Abaixo na View tenho o seguinte script que peguei na seção de API da Google
As variáveis do script não estão pegando os valores

```
        var a1 = @(ViewBag.Latitude);
        var a2 = @(ViewBag.Longitude);
```

Parte da View referente ao Google Maps

```
<h3>Localização</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() {

        var a1 = @(ViewBag.Latitude);
        var a2 = @(ViewBag.Longitude);

        var uluru = { lat: a1, lng: a2 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: uluru,
            gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MINHA CHAVE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa noite.

Pelo que vejo a sua lógica está correta, o único item que faz com que você não consiga transportar dados (decimais, neste caso) entre Controller e JavaScript, é que o separador de casas decimais de sua aplicação esteja diferente. Provavelmente está "," (vírgula), então ao serializar o valor, o JavaScript não entende isso como um separador válido, pois o mesmo usa o separador "." (ponto).

Para correção, é necessário mudar configurações na cultura de sua aplicação.

Como segue o exemplo:

```
//Recupera o nome da cultura que está sendo utilizada pela aplicação
string strCulturaAtual = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
//Cria um novo objeto que poderá personalizar configurações de sua cultura
//Como neste caso, que usaremos para casas decimais, mas neste, 
//também é possível configurar informações de formato de data por exemplo.
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(strCulturaAtual);
//Novo separador de casas decimais
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
//Altera a cultura atual, pela nova que criamos.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```

Logo após essa configuração, você irá preencher a ViewBag (fixei os valores, para ficar explicito o nosso objetivo), como o exemplo:

```
ViewBag.Latitude = -21.1234567;
ViewBag.Longitude = -51.1234567;
```

E no JavaScript, poderá recuperar o valor normalmente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var latitude = @ViewBag.Latitude;
    var longitude = @ViewBag.Longitude;
</script>
```

Com isso, creio que você consiga resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Amigo @Wesley Ferreira consegui resolver desta maneira var latitude = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Latitude)) e assim a variável pega o valor com ponto, e assim passando para o Google Maps os valores correspondente corretamente.